# How to dynamically set the size of Int?

Tags: alloy

The  model below represents a portion of a model of the binary search algorithm.

One of the key steps in the binary search algorithm is to compute the middle between `low` and `high`. It is computed by adding `low` to `high` and then dividing by 2.

So, my model has a field `low` of type `Int`, `high` of type `Int`, and `mid` of type `Int`.

When the model is run, the default size of Int is a 4-bit signed integer, with a range of values between -8 and +7. If `low` has the value 6 and `high` has the value 6, then 6 + 6 = 12 which is too big and the sum overflows to -4. Divide by 2 yields -2 and `mid` has a negative value ... ouch!

I want to assert that `mid` is always positive. But, as described above, it could be negative if Int is not set to a sufficiently large size. Is there a way to dynamically set the size of Int?

I would like my assert to say something like this:

```
for some size of Int
    mid_is_low_plus_high_div_2 =>
        Test.mid >= 0
```

Is there a way to express that?

```
one sig Test {
    low: Int,
    high: Int,
    mid: Int
} {
    low in {i: Int | i >= 0 }
    high in {i: Int | i >= 0 }
}

pred mid_is_low_plus_high_div_2 {
   Test.mid = div[plus[Test.low, Test.high], 2]
}

assert mid_is_always_positive {
    mid_is_low_plus_high_div_2 =>
        Test.mid >= 0
}
check mid_is_always_positive
```

Comment: Use a bigger int; do the mid calculation in a safe way;use bignums. But I'm not sure which of these answers your question. Where do the requirements come from?

Comment: Quick tip: You can forbid integer overflow in the Alloy analyzer options,